# POST JSON object to C# ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, json, http

I'm unable to post JSON object in the body of my HTTP message.

I have even tried this

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
```

but it still didn't work

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    type:<br>
    <input type="number" ng-model="config.type"><br>
    Id:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="config.Id">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.config = {type:0, Id:"786"};
    $scope.submit = function() {
        var data = $scope.config;
        //$http.post("http://localhost:8612/api/values/", data);
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8612/api/values/", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        alert("Done");
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error that is my object is empty in this method

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]object c)
```

Answer (score 2):

So the deserialization is failing probably. having the request model as `object` type is wrong; instead you should define a proper request model and use that rather like

```
public class ApiRequestModel 
{
   // define all your required properties client going to send
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ApiRequestModel c)
```